# Losing scope when I refresh a page

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I have a problem with $scope. In my application I have make a paged list. To make this, I make a method which return a list with the number of elements and it works.Now I want make a modal to filter the list. So when I send the research my scope is good with my research parameters. But when I change page the controller is reinstanciate and I loose my parameters. How to prevent the reload of the scope or keep the previous scope.

It's a part of my controller:

```
    //request of research
        $scope.edit = function (id) {
            var customer = getCustomer(id);
            var reqEditCustomer = $http({ url: '/api/customers/', dataType: 'json', method: 'PUT', data: JSON.stringify(customer), contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' });
            reqEditCustomer.success(function (dataResult) {
                $scope.customer = dataResult;
                $scope.cancel();
            });
            $scope.customers = GetListFiltered(customer.lastName, customer.firstName, customer.address, customer.town, customer.zipCode, $scope.skip, $scope.numPerPage);
    }
```

//GetListFiltered

```
function GetListFiltered(lastName, firstName, address, town, zipCode, skip, take) {
     var reqSearchCustomers = $http({ url: '/api/customers/GetFilteredList', params: { 'lastName': lastName, 'firstName': firstName, 'address': address, 'town': town, 'zipCode': zipCode, 'skip': skip, 'take': take } });
            reqSearchCustomers.success(function (dataResult) {
                $scope.customers = dataResult;
            });
            var reqgetcustomers = $http({ url: 'api/customers/GetNbCustomer', params: { 'lastName': lastName, 'firstName': firstName, 'address': address, 'town': town, 'zipCode': zipCode, 'skip': -1, 'take': -1 } });;
                reqgetcustomers.success(function (dataresult) {
                    $scope.itemCount = dataresult;
                    $scope.nbPage = Math.ceil($scope.itemCount / $scope.numPerPage);
                    console.log('       itemCount = ' + $scope.itemCount);
                });
            $scope.skip = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage);
            $scope.nbPage = Math.ceil($scope.itemCount / $scope.numPerPage);
            }
```

So that it's work I recover the params to research, the number of items and page. But when I load an another page of my paged List I loose my scope and so it's reload my entire list of customer.

//method changePage()

```
$scope.changePage = function (curPage) {
$scope.currentPage = curPage;
            $scope.skip = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage);
            $scope.customers = GetListFiltered($scope.lastName, $scope.firstName, $scope.address, $scope.town, $scope.zipCode, $scope.skip, $scope.numPerPage);
            $scope.nbPage = Math.ceil($scope.itemCount / $scope.numPerPage);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like [Angular Locker](https://github.com/tymondesigns/angular-locker) to persist state.

It has especially a nice feature called ["binding to $scope"](https://github.com/tymondesigns/angular-locker#binding-to-a-scope-property) that lets you directly map `$scope` properties to bits and pieces in your local or session storage.

You could do this like:

```
locker.bind($scope, 'customers');
```

Comment: Thanks,I put time to inject the dependancy with the asp.net but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the cache:true in the $http service. so if its again calling the customers list it will not go to the server.

Comment: I can't because I manage the paged list with this request on server IIS. I have to reload my paged list often. So I can't block the refresh of this request.